# Chai-http doesn't seem to accept header always sends 401

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I am trying to test my API routes that are protected by using jsonwebtoken.

I have tested my routes in postman and have gotten the correct results however running the same tests using mocha/chai/chai-http is not working.

Everytime I test a protected route I receive a 401 'unauthorized'

```
describe('user', () => {
    let user, token

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await dropDb()

        user = await new User({ email: 'testing@test.com', password: 'password' }).save()
        const payload = { userid: user.id, role: user.roles.title, status: user.roles.status }
        token = jwt.sign(payload, secret, { expiresIn: 3600 })
    })

    it('should return a list of users when logged in', async () => {
        console.log(token)

        const result = await chai.request(app)
            .get('/api/user')
            .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)

        expect(result).to.have.status(200)
        expect(result).to.be.json
    })
})
```

My gut feeling was that there was somehow a race condition where the token being passed into the set wasn't finished being signed before the test ran. But inside the result it appears that my token has been set.

[image]

Additionally if I console.log the token after I can see that it matches the token created. Anybody run into a similar issue?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the correct secret? Also, have you tried taking the generated token from you test and sending that via Postman to try and debug it?

Comment: Yea I did that and it worked (in postman) but still not my test which was confusing. However, I seem to have just stumbled upon the weirdest 'solution' ever... I removed the token variable I initialised at the top of my test and instead added a token prop. `user.token = jwt.sign....` and then called the token later on using user.token and now everything seems to work. Have no idea why